# Unable to join this clan at the time

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am trying to join a level 11 clan but when i click to join, an error appears saying "Unable to join the clan at this time, please try again later". I again tried to join that clan after 2 hours but still no luck. I tried to join another level 11 clan but still i am getting the same message. Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ClashOfClans/comments/3djrtz/misc_unable_to_join_clan/cvq492w) and a few other places, this may be due to the clan having 10 pending join requests, and thus you cannot join until at least one gets cleared. The 10 request join limit seems to have been put in place to prevent spamming of players trying to join a clan.